# rewritebase in subdomain makes php a downloadable file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a big problem understanding how htaccess works.

**Case 1: I have my htaccess in root (/public_html/) directory**

This is the content of my htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "index.php?_url=$1" [QSA,L]
RewriteRule /*\.(css|js|gif|png|jpe?g|ico|swf|csv|html|xlsx|xls|xml)$ - [NC,L]
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

That perfectly converted, say "http://sitename.com/stuff/here" to "http://sitename.com/?_url=stuff/here"

**BUT! Case 2, I have my htaccess in a subdomain**

**The goal**: To convert "http://mini.sitename.com/stuff/here" to "http://mini.sitename.com/?_url=stuff/here"

In this case if I put my htaccess either **inside /public_html/mini/** or **inside /public_html/** directory where that htaccess has this content:

```
RewriteBase /mini/
# the rest are similar to above
```

http://mini.sitename.com/ **DOWNLOADS** the index.php file instead of running it! How crazy is that?!

So my questions are:

1. Obviously, what do I need to write in .htaccess file, and where should I put that .htaccess file, to achieve that goal?
2. Why did the downloading happen? I mean, I don't even.. what?

Answer (score 0):

Just place this in `/mini/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Assuming `DocumentRoot` for `mini` subdomain is `/public_html/mini/`.

Comment: Thank you, now if I access with http://mini.triodigitalagency.com/index.php it worked, but it still downloads the file when I accessed it with http://mini.triodigitalagency.com ...Do you know why, perhaps?